# Possible to pass along a ngclick value to a function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Is there a possible solution to increment a variable on each click and pass along to a function? I tried doing something like this but it doesn't work.

```
<button ng-click="count++" ng-init="count=1" (click)="assignTasks(count)">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can both increment and call assignTasks function inside the same ng-click, there is no need for (click)="assignTasks(count)"

```
<button ng-init="count=1" ng-click="count = count + 1;assignTasks(count)">Click</button>
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/8fY4WHlF3eFvtDqoUG9q?p=preview)**

Comment: I tried copy pasting this code, However on my editor(WebStorm) it says ng identifier 'name' is not defined at the Hello{{name}} part.

Comment: just take the button part please, Hello {{name}} part is the default code generated by plunker which you do not need.

Comment: This did the trick thanks! I wish I could pass the count to a method outside the controller but I guess thats not possible. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a function to do this, you can just increment it on the template.

**`ng-click="count = count+1"`**

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('test',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="test" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<button   ng-init="count=1" ng-click="count = count+1"> Pass {{count}} </button>
</body>
```

If you still need to pass to a function use **`ng-click = "assignTasks(count)"`**

and increment count inside the function of controller